# Zoom in for selected lands in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, zoom

I am trying to make a selection from a search result. I managed to make the selection on the map using the code below.

Now my problem is that when I select one or more buildings with the same style, it does not automatically zoom in on the respective lands. I would also like to zoom in on the selected land.

My code:

```
var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty ();

var selected_stile = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: makePattern()}),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [102,255,51], width: 3
    }),
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
    placement: 'center',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'white', width: 23
    })
  })
});

imobile.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
  feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
  
  var array = id_teren.split(",");
  for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    var data = "";
    if($('#etc_tarla').is(":checked")){ data = "T:"+feature.get('tarla')+"  "; }
    if($('#etc_parcela').is(":checked")){ data = data+"P:"+feature.get('parcela')+"  "; }
    if($('#etc_suprafata').is(":checked")){ data = data+"S:"+feature.get('suprafata')+"MP.  "; }
    if($('#etc_proprietari').is(":checked")){ data = data+"P:"+feature.get('proprietari')+"  "; }
    if($('#etc_eterra').is(":checked")){ data = data+"C.F.:"+feature.get('e_terra')+"  "; }

     if(feature.get('text') == array[i]){
        console.log('GASITTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT');
        var feature = imobile.getSource().getFeatureById(array[i]);
        
        selected_stile.getText().setText(data);
        feature.setStyle(selected_stile);
        ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
        
     }
  }   
});
```

Comment: You are extending `extent`, but I don't see it initially defined anywhere, neither it's being used to zoom to this extent.

Comment: Here is stated a little above the above code: var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty ();

Comment: Please edit your question with the code from comment. And then, where is this extent used to set view zoom?

Comment: Yes for the zoom view.

Comment: What do you mean by "Yes for the zoom view."? I don't see any code setting the view zoom.

Comment: That's what I'd like to do just because I don't know how .. I tried this code: ol.extent.extend (extent, feature.getGeometry (). GetExtent ()); but unfortunately I didn't manage to make it work :(

Comment: so I want that when selecting certain lands from the list through a checkbox to look in my features the respective ids to color them and to zoom in to the land to see better if there is only one if there are more then zoom in until it covers them all to look good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zoom map to the desired extent, you can use map view `.fit` method (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit).

If your map object is `map`, then this would look like this:

```
map.getView().fit(extent, {size: map.getSize()});
```